# How to delete selected Cart Item using Django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

*I'm using Django as backend, PostgresSQL as DB and HTML, CSS and Javascript as frontend*

I'm calling **Django API** with the help of *Javascript* to show the cart item to authenticated `user`

**serializer.py**

```
from .models import *
from rest_framework import serializers

class productserializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def showproduct(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        result = Cart.objects.filter(user = request.user)
        serialize = productserializers(result, many = True)
        return Response(serialize.data)
```

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/showdata',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
          var row = 
          $('<tr><td style="font-style:bold">'
          +data[i].product.name+'</td><td style="font-style:bold">'
          +data[i].product.price+'</td><td><a href='
          +data[i].product.link_href+'><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Buy</button></a></td><td><a href='#'><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">DELETE</button></a></td></tr>');
          $("#tableProduct").append(row);
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Well, from above code on **`main.js`**

```
...
<td><a href='#'><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">DELETE</button></a></td>
...
```

In this line I want to implement delete function. Where user can delete the selected item from cart. So, How to implement delete function that can delete the item from cart and show the response in Template.

Here is how I'm adding the cart item in DJANGO ADMINISTRATION.

**view.py**

```
def addProduct(request):
    user = request.user
    product_id = request.GET.get('product_id')
    product_cart = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    Cart(user=user, product=product_cart).save()
    return render(request, 'cart/addtocart.html')
```

## EDIT 1

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/showdata ',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
          var row = 
          $('<tr><td style="font-style:bold">'
          +data[i].product.name+'</td><td style="font-style:bold">'
          +data[i].product.price+'</td><td><a href='
          +data[i].product.link_href+'><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Buy</button></a></td><td><button onclick="destoryCart('+data[i].product.id+')" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">DELETE</button></td></tr>');
          $("#tablebuild").append(row);
        }
     
      }
    });
});

const destoryCart = (id) => {
  let url = `{% url 'main:cart_destroy' ${id} %}`
  $.ajax({
      beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', '{{ csrf_token }}');},
      url: url,
      type: 'DELETE',
      success: (data) => {
          console.log("deleted!")
      },
      error: (err) => {
          console.log(err);
      }
  });
} 
</script>
```

**urls.py**

```
path('cart_destroy/', views.CartDestroyAPIView.as_view(), name ='cart_destroy'),
```

**views.py**

```
class CartDestroyAPIView(DestroyAPIView): # DeleteView
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated] # Or anything else you want
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]  # Or anything else you want
    serializer_class = productserializers
    queryset = Cart.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can delete your cards:

```
class CartDestroyAPIView(DestroyAPIView): # DeleteView
"""
Cart Destroy API View
"""
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated] # Or anything else you want
authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]  # Or anything else you want
serializer_class = productserializers
queryset = Cart.objects.all()
```

And for JS part you can create a function that gets an id and send delete request to your `CartDestroyAPIView` endpoint:

```
const destoryCart = (id) => {

    let url = `your end point/${id}`; 


    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', '{{ csrf_token }}');},
        url: url,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: (data) => {
            console.log("deleted!")
        },
        error: (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

}
```

Now when you are creating your Cart Lists in the `success` of your ajax call you can do this with your delete button:

```
`<td>
     <button onclick="destoryCart(${cart.id})" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
        DELETE
     </button>
 </td>`
```

in your case will be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/showdata',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
      var row = 
      $('<tr><td style="font-style:bold">'
      +data[i].product.name+'</td><td style="font-style:bold">'
      +data[i].product.price+'</td><td><a href='
      +data[i].product.link_href+'><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Buy</button></a></td><td><button onclick="destoryCart('+data[i].product.id+')" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">DELETE</button></td></tr>');
      $("#tableProduct").append(row);
    }
  }
});
```

});

if you are writing your js inside a .js file you can't get `csrf_token` like this, instead you can do [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/).
***Tip:***
you backticks(`) when you want use your variable inside a string in js

```
let name = "John";
console.log(`My name is ${name}`);
```

Comment: How to implement it in AJAX ? The Delete button which I mentioned I want to implement there. How it can happen?

Comment: Was it helpful, tell me if you get errors @santoshChauhan

Comment: I think i Should this JS file in HTML it will be better. And I will let u know as soon as possible

Comment: you can also get your csrf token in your js file check out the link that i put, it's fron django documentation just copy the function and you can use it

Comment: Hello sir, How the url will look: `path('cart_destroy/', views.CartDestroyAPIView.as_view(), name ='cart_destroy'),` while implementing this I'm getting error as `Could not parse the remainder: '${id}' from '${id}'`

Comment: I'm getting error in this line `44     const destoryCart = (id) => {
45       let url = `{% url 'main:cart_destroy' ${id} %}`
46       $.ajax({ `

Comment: Edit your question and put what you have written @santoshChauhan

Comment: Edited Sir, Please do have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233823/discussion-between-mojixcoder-and-santosh-chauhan).

Comment: showing error as: `jquery.min.js:2 DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/showdata/2342; 404 (Not Found)` with secondline  `{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}`

Answer (score -1):

```
def delete_cart_item(request):
    cart_item_id = request.GET.get('cart_item_id')
    CartItem.objects.filter(cart__user=rquest.user.id,id=cart_item_id)
    return render(request, your template)
```